# codeigniter form not submitting fields

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

I'm a newbie for codeigniter. I'm stuck at a problem, that my form is not posting values, I dont know why. 
Current site works fine on local server and my testing server. As I transferred complete site on clients server, this problem occurred.

I have checked, htaccess is enabled. I'm also pasting my view, and controller. 
Please help me

**VIEW**

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="index.php/search/make_url">
    <div class="search_form">

        <label for="shop"></label>
        <select name="category" id="select">
          <option value="0">-- Shops / Webshops --</option>
          <?php 
            $cats=load_categories();
            foreach($cats as $cat){
          ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $cat->cat_name_en."---".$cat->catId;?>"><?php echo $cat->cat_name_en;?></option>
          <?php }?>
        </select>
        <select name="product">
          <option value="0">-- <?php echo $this->lang->line("text_select_prod");?> --</option>
          <?php 
            $cats=load_products();
            foreach($cats as $cat){
          ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $cat->p_name_en;?>---<?php echo $cat->pId;?>"><?php echo $cat->p_name_en;?></option>
          <?php }?>
        </select>
        <label for="select2"></label>
        <select name="brand" id="brand">
          <option value="0">-- <?php echo $this->lang->line("text_select_chose_brand");?> --</option>
          <?php 
            $cats=load_brands();
            foreach($cats as $cat){
          ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $cat->brand_name_en;?>---<?php echo $cat->brandId;?>"><?php echo $cat->brand_name_en;?></option>
          <?php }?>
        </select>
        <label for="select3"></label>
        <select name="country" id="country"  onchange="getCity(this.value);">
          <option value="0">-- <?php echo $this->lang->line("text_select_country");?> ---</option>
          <?php 
            $cats=load_country();
            foreach($cats as $cat){
          ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $cat->cn_name;?>---<?php echo $cat->cnId;?>"><?php echo $cat->cn_name;?></option>
          <?php }?>
        </select>
        <label for="select4"></label>
        <div id="cityBlock">
        <select name="city" id="city">
          <option value="0">-- <?php echo $this->lang->line("text_select_city");?> --</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="btn" value="<?php echo $this->lang->line("text_btn_submit");?>">

    </div>
    </form>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function make_url()
{
    $url=$this->uri->assoc_to_uri($_POST);
    redirect(base_url()."index.php/search/for/". $url);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: check the server error logs.

Comment: What's the output if you change make_url() to the following?
public function make_url()
{
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo $base_url();
}

Comment: this looks like a very messed up implementation to me, why dont you explain your requirement and we'll try to give you a better way to implement this

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, but I dont have access to log files.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions,but I dont have access to log files.
When I add var_dump($_POST)echo base_url.It dsiplays array(0) { } and corresponding url.
The view contains simple functions defined in helpers,like to get record for country, city etc etc. Whereas controller collects post data and convert them into form field name/value format e.g  index.php/country/1/City/2/brand/Lewis  and so on.

This is working fine everywhere but nt on client's servr. Pleaselet me know,if there are some other settings or some other point missing from server config or CI config, orI can do this in some other way.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but I managed to sort out this shit, and this was due to use of base tag, having site base url. Dont know why but I removed that line and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem later. **Problem was base tag used in Head tag**. I simply removed it, and website was functional.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this way:

```
<?=form_open('immovable/personal/add_personal');?>
<input type='text' id='fname' name='fname' required />
<input type='text' id='lname' name='lname' required />
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
<?=form_close()?>
```

Comment: Thanks I made that work. Problem was due to form's action, and base tag. I just removed that base tag, and every thing is working fine. But reason is still unknown

Answer (score 0):

`$config[suffix]` is the solution for the above problem

Refer this [link](https://github.com/longma/RestaurantReview/wiki/URL-Query-Problem-In-Pagination-Link-For-CodeIgniter) for better explanation